# Aurora- clone production db as a qa db daily

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We have an aurora database(aws) that we use for production. We would like to have a clone database that will be updated on a daily basis and will be used for qa(one way sync from the production to qa db). What is the best way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's an open source Python Library that can do this for you, or you could take a look at that approach and do the same:

https://github.com/blacklocus/aurora-echo

Answer (score 0):

You can launch following script daily:

1. Convert production automatic snapshot to manual: aws rds copy-db-cluster-snapshot
2. Now you can share your manual snapshot with test account: aws rds modify-db-snapshot-attributes  --attribute-name restore --values-to-add dev-account-id
3. Restore your snapshot to  cluster with aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot
4. Add instance
5. Rename db cluster  to  (it is about 10 seconds)
6. Rename db cluster  to  (it is about 10 seconds)
7. If new cluster works, you can delete  cluster with instances.